# How can I kill a screen session running a Minecraft server and save the world?

Tags: server, process, minecraft

I am running a dedicated Minecraft server, and I want it to restart every night at midnight. I'm running it in a `screen` session so I can easily access it. However, if I just run `screen -X -S server quit`, it does not save the world. I will use `cron` to restart it every night.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to make sense to backup the world before shutting down the screen session.

I would think this would help:
http://www.scaine.net/site/2013/08/backing-up-your-minecraft-server-in-ubuntu%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF/

or this:
https://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/minecraft-custom-linux-backups-using-crontab-and-screen.45575/

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [this post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15151/please-do-not-use-links-as-entire-answers).

Comment: Point taken, I was just trying to be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: I completely understand - and to an extent, the links are helpful, but if they ever go down... Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 1):

Filing this under "Who Knew?" on Stack Exchange we have a sister-site called **Arcade** where your question has an answer:

- [Is it safe to close Minecraft's multiplayer server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19914/is-it-safe-to-close-minecrafts-multiplayer-server)

On our sister-site **Unix & Linux** there is this answer:

- [Minecraft server startup/shutdown with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302733/minecraft-server-startup-shutdown-with-systemd)

This will probably suit your needs better.